error while deploying Django project in virtual private server in hostinger
when i try to start nginx its works well but i cant see my site in my domain and when i looks for a error log its says this
gunicorn[313208]: [2024-08-14 05:56:29 +0000] [313208] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000) 

so i run this command
sudo lsof -i :80


to check which process is using this port. I saw that these
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   316452     root    6u  IPv4 1073432      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   316452     root    7u  IPv6 1073433      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   316453 www-data    6u  IPv4 1073432      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   316453 www-data    7u  IPv6 1073433      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)


process are using the port which are my nginx. even though i kill that ports using this sudo kill -9 316452 316453 command. Its still appearing again. can anyone help ?
tried these codes already
 gunicorn[313208]: [2024-08-14 05:56:29 +0000] [313208] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 8000) 
 sudo lsof -i :80
 sudo kill -9 316452 316453


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That means the NGINX is running on port 80 and your are trying to run the gunicorn(Django) on the same port. Thus creating a conflict. You can fix this in 2 ways

Stop the nginx thus you can free the port 80 and then you can run the django on the same port. Although I would not recommend this
best practice will be to run the gunicorn on a different port, i.e 7000, and reverse proxy the incoming request from nginx to gunicorn(now running on localhost)

